# Why can't my 'getData' function be accessed by my code?

Tags: javascript

For college I have to make a javascript game with an MVC style coding. (Model, View, Controller). I am pretty new to this so please don't be too hard. I'm getting the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined". Can someone help me identify the problem? I'm sure my code is riddled with errors. I'm trying to get the player model drawn on canvas. Any and all help would be appreciated! Here is my code:

```
var GOBLINS = GOBLINS || {};

GOBLINS.View = function() {};

GOBLINS.View.prototype.draw = function(objects) {

    for(i=0; i < objects.length; i++) {
          ctx.drawImage(objects[i],0,0);
    };
};

GOBLINS.View.prototype.update = function(data){
    this.draw(data); 
};

GOBLINS.Model = function() {
    this.data = [];
};

GOBLINS.Model.prototype.player = {
    hitPoints: 25,
    x: 15,
    y: 20,
    img: new Image(),
    push: function() {
    data.push(GOBLINS.Model.player.img);
    }
};

GOBLINS.Model.prototype.getData = function(recall){
      recall(this.data);
};

GOBLINS.Controller = function() {
    var M = new GOBLINS.Model();
    var V = new GOBLINS.View();

    this.mainLoop();
};

GOBLINS.Controller.prototype.mainLoop = function() {
    var self = this;   

    this.M.getData(function(data){
        self.V.update(data);
    });

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
        self.mainLoop();
    });
};

window.onload = function() {
    var game = new GOBLINS.Controller();

    GOBLINS.Model.player.img.src = "Image/Player.png";
    var c=document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `M` and `V` are not part of `this`. They are locally scoped to the controller method.

```
var M = new GOBLINS.Model();
var V = new GOBLINS.View();
```

should be

```
this.M = new GOBLINS.Model();
this.V = new GOBLINS.View();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I incorrectly wrote down the teachers code.